# Как передать переменную методом POST?

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails, ruby

В документации у CDEK написано:

> Для использования необходимо отправить POST запрос на URL:
>   **<сервер>/new_orders.php**, например,
>   https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php с заполненной переменной
>   **$_POST['xml_request']**, в которой передается содержимое XML фaйла.

И дальше идет описание данных.

```
DeliveryRequest
Number 
Date
Account
Secure
OrderCount
```

Не совсем понимаю что в итоге нужно передать. Я должен сформировать xml-файл? Или в виде url можно передать параметры(тогда как это должно выглядеть)?

**UPD:** Документация: http://www.edostavka.ru/website/edostavka/upload/custom/files/CDEK_integrator.zip (Для интеграции)
- Формат обмена данными «СДЭК» - Интернет-Магазин
- Раздел 3 (список заказов на доставку)

Comment: ссылочку на доку прикрепите

Comment: прикрепил к телу вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно приложенной документации, в xml_request POST параметре должно быть содержимое в таком виде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DeliveryRequest>
    <Number>11</Number>
    <Date>2015-01-01</Date>
    <Account>111</Account>
    <Secure>1</Secure>
    <OrderCount>1</OrderCount>
</DeliveryRequest>
```

пример на CURL:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost/new_orders.php \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'xml_request=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<DeliveryRequest>
    <Number>11</Number>
    <Date>2015-01-01</Date>
    <Account>111</Account>
    <Secure>1</Secure>
    <OrderCount>1</OrderCount>
</DeliveryRequest>'
```

Comment: Я это понимаю. Я должен файл отправить? т.е. как это должно выглядеть (скажем на бекенде или через curl)?

Comment: например `https://integration.cdek.ru/new_orders.php?xml_request=(и что тут нужно указать?)`

Comment: @dmitriy это вы через GET передаете, надо через POST.  пример на CURL выше добавил. через ruby можете сделать согласно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660330/how-to-transfer-a-post-request-in-curl-into-a-ruby-script

Comment: спасибо, я не понимал что от меня требуется) хоть с места сдвинулся.